# How to re-name and reference COUNT(*) in a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm trying to use a COUNT(*) in a SELECT statement. However, I need to re-name it and be able to reference it for a WHERE clause.

I've tried using AS, and I've tried omitting the AS, as it doesn't seem to be necessary according to the oracle page: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm

Tried wrapping the new identifier in quotes, but that didn't work either.

This works, but give an oracle-generated name for the count, which isn't ideal, and I wouldn't know how to reference the count for each row:

```
SELECT
    school_name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM liason_to
    WHERE school_name = s.school_name)
FROM school s;
```

This is what I've attempted but won't work:

```
SELECT
    school_name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS numLiasons
    FROM liason_to
    WHERE school_name = s.school_name)
FROM school s
WHERE numLiasons > 0;
```

It doesn't make the column name "numLiasons", and the where clause at the end doesn't know what numLiasons is, so that fails.

Comment: ```(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM liason_to
    WHERE school_name = s.school_name) AS numLiasons```

Try this and let me knwo

Comment: That does fix the column name! (thanks!) However, if I try to reference it in the WHERE at the bottom it still doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alias a column by simply putting a name after it, optionally with the keyword `AS` in between. It's essentially the same as you already do with the tables.

```
SELECT school_name,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM liason_to l
               WHERE l.school_name = s.school_name) AS numliasons
       FROM school s;
```

or simply

```
SELECT school_name,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM liason_to l
               WHERE l.school_name = s.school_name) numliasons
       FROM school s;
```

But you cannot use aliases in the `WHERE` clause (aliasing is happening after the records have been selected by the criteria in the `WHERE` clause). You have to repeat the expession.

```
SELECT school_name,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM liason_to l
               WHERE l.school_name = s.school_name) numliasons
       FROM school s
       WHERE (SELECT count(*)
                     FROM liason_to l
                     WHERE l.school_name = s.school_name) > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! You mentioning: "aliasing is happening after the records have been selected by the criteria in the WHERE clause" clears up for me why it wasn't working. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the subquery using  an join and group by ..and you can assign the anme you prefers as alias

```
SELECT s.school_name, COUNT(*) as my_count 
FROM school s 
INNER JOIN liason_to l on s.school_name = l.school_name 
GROUP BY s.school_name
```

using your code you could simply assign an alias  at the (subselected ) column

```
SELECT
    school_name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM liason_to
    WHERE school_name = s.school_name) as my_name 
FROM school s;
```

anyway for filter an aggregated  result you could use having but for `count(*)`
remember that this work only for not null rows  so normally count(*) is > 0

Comment: Why not `HAVING` clause in first aggregate (that is missing `FROM`)?

Comment: @Parfait  .. thanks  .. from added ..   .. HAVING > 0   .. should not be need  because count(*) return only value for not null rows  so normally is always > 0

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference the aliased name in the WHERE clause, but you can do this:

```
SELECT
    t.school_name,
    t.numLiasons
FROM (
  SELECT  
    s.school_name,
    (
      SELECT COUNT(*) 
      FROM liason_to
      WHERE school_name = s.school_name
    ) AS numLiasons
  FROM school s
) t
WHERE t.numLiasons > 0;
```